# How to set passed values into template's fields?

Tags: javascript, templates, tornado

In tornado's template in I passed from code dictionary data with keys username and code

```
data = {'username' : 'pal', 'code' : 16281}
```

in ready function I am trying to set passed values to two inputs on page

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var d = "{{data}}";
        alert(d);
        $('#code').val({{data['code']}});
        $('#username').val(d['username']);
    });
```

...

```
<label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" class="large_input">
 <label for="code" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Code:</label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Code" name="code" id="code" class="large_input">
```

Alert shows that dictionary is ok, but when I try to access on any way I got undefined value. I tried with passed data and with js dictionary d but it didn't work.
How to set passed values into template's fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML this would work:

```
<input value="{{data["username"]}}" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" class="large_input">
```

For your JS I image you need to write this instead:

```
$('#code').val('{{data['code']}}');
```